# How to edit multiple photos in Google photos by using Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-photos, google-photos-api

For editing a single photo:

I need go to specific album in Google photos. Then, after clicking on a picture there is an edit option. Which has list of available filters. From there, I can select any filter and click **Done**.

But, I want to know. How to edit multiple photos at once using **Google Apps Script**.

Can any one give reference link or script?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as it's suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/) does not provide access to these functions. There are currently only a handful of API resources that are centered around uploading content and adding them to albums.

**AFAIK, there is no way to access the browser-/app-based photo editing options.**

A bit of additional information regarding using the Photos API from Google Apps ScriptGoogle Apps Script has some [Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) which handle the authorization workflow for the public REST APIs, but currently Google Photos is not an available advanced service, which means to use it you would need to treat it as an external API and handle the authorization workflow yourself.